# Problems with captions in the environment  wrapfigure

Tags: errors, environments, captions, wrapfigure

I'm dealing with a rather weird issue. Using the enviroment `\wrapfigure`, I receive an error message

```
undefined control sequence \float@caption ... oxrestore ... 
\normalize @fs@capt ...
```

let alone the caption doesn't show up the .pdf; while `caption` is working in any other environments (`figure`, `subfigure`, `tabular`). What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome. Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: @Thanos You are lucky since I just got my crystal ball back from repair ;-)  (See my answer below)

Answer (score 6):

Remove `\restylefloat{figure}` (and `\restylefloat{table}`) from your document preamble. In most cases it is simply not needed and it is only in the preamble because it was copied from another LaTeX document given by a friend or colleague (who did not know what `\restylefloat` does either).

But if you really need it (and really know what's good for and why you need it), you can try the following load order of packages:

```
...
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
...
\floatstyle{boxed} % or whatever
\restylefloat{figure}
...
```

This should fix the issue, too.

Comment: You are a God!!!
And you are a crystall ball fortune teller!!!
You couldn't have been more precise.
Indeed, the preable was from a mix from net/friend.
Thank you sooooooooooooooo much!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Thanos: Please upvote the answer, and accept it - this is the best way to give thanks here.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanos has not enough reputation yet to upvote.